# How to get the market products from checkbox after clicking button?

Tags: php, symfony

I have a list of products and every product has a checkbox. I want to get the market products when I mark them and click the button "Add To Cart". When I try to dump the products, there are no data in the array.

Here is my Twig

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <div style="text-align: center;">
        <h2><u>Recent Products</u></h2>
        <hr>
        <form action="{{ path('cart_add') }}" method="post">
    {% for product in products %}
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-7">
                    <img src="/images/products/{{ product.image }}" alt="" width="300" height="250">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5">
                <h4><b>Name: </b>{{ product.name }}</h4>
                <h4><b>Description: </b></h4>
                 Mark It <input type="checkbox" value="{{ product.id }}" name="products[]">
                <p>{{ product.description }}</p>
                <a class="btn btn-primary" href="/products/details/{{ product.id }}">View Product <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
                <br>
                <br>
                {% if is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN') or is_granted('ROLE_EDITOR') %}
                <a href="/products/edit/{{ product.id }}" class="btn btn-default">Edit Product</a>
                <a href="/products/delete/{{ product.id }}" class="btn btn-danger">Delete Product</a>
                    {% endif %}
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr>
    {% endfor %}
            <a href="/cart/add" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span> Add To Cart</a>
        </form>
        <div class="navigation">
            {{ knp_pagination_render(products) }}
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

And the CartController

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class CartController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/cart/add", name="cart_add")
     */
    public function addToCartAction(Request $request)
    {
       var_dump($request->get('products', []));
       die();
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/cart/show", name="cart_list")
     */
    public function listCartAction()
    {   
        return $this->render('cart/cart.view.html.twig', [
            'products' => ...
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Create a "submit" input/button instead of `<a href="/cart/add" ...` otherwise the form data doesn't send.

Comment: try to use  <a href="{{ url('your_route_name',{'id': product.id) }}"> , it should work.. regards

Comment: or <a href="{{ url('your_route_name' }}"> for add to cart...